# Email rejected as Spam by Gmail

Tags: domain-name-system, email, spam, gmail

My domain is apitrak.com registered at gandi.net. For my mail I use Apple Mail and th Gendi.net SMTP server throught SSL.

When I respond to a Gmail address, I get an "Undelivered Mail" response by Google, informing me that my email was treated as Spam:

```
This is the mail system at host relay5-d.mail.gandi.net.

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

                  The mail system

<xxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com>: host
   gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c06::1b] said: 550-5.7.1
   [2001:4b98:c:538::197      12] Our system has detected that this 550-5.7.1
   message is likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent
   550-5.7.1 to Gmail, this message has been blocked. Please visit 550 5.7.1
   https://support.google.com/mail/answer/188131 for more information.
   9si38384151wmi.71 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command)
Reporting-MTA: dns; relay5-d.mail.gandi.net
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 2ECF641C09D
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; vincent.le@apitrak.com
Arrival-Date: Wed, 13 Jan 2016 12:56:41 +0100 (CET)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
Original-Recipient: rfc822;xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Remote-MTA: dns; gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.7.1 [2001:4b98:c:538::197      12] Our system has
   detected that this 550-5.7.1 message is likely unsolicited mail. To reduce
   the amount of spam sent 550-5.7.1 to Gmail, this message has been blocked.
   Please visit 550 5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/188131 for
   more information. 9si38384151wmi.71 - gsmtp
```

Following the link, it tells me to avoid mass mailing: that is absolutely not my case (simple response or fwded response).

It also tells that I should not "change the envelope sender when forwarding email to Gmail." But I don't know what that means.

Any idea?

Comment: If you post here, remove email addresses and other sensitive info. Your own, that's your choice, but the receiver address, that's not what we (or she) wants. Editing the answer will hide it here, but it's still in the history.

Comment: seems that the SPF authentication is the good solution

Comment: seems that the SPF authentication is the good solution, but I still have a problem when responding to a specific gmail address. Maybe it needs some time to recognize my new settings.

Comment: DNS updates can take up to 24 hours, but generally Google should update this faster.